# How to say "I need more of X"? - usage of 「ひつよう」

Tags: usage

For example, for "I think I need more teachers" - would  「私は先生が多いひつようとすると思います」　be the correct usage for 「ひつよう」？

Answer (score 2):

"先生が多い必要とすると思います" is not valid:

- "先生が - 必要とする" means "The teacher(s) need[s] (something)". When we need teachers, use either "先生を必要とする" or "先生が必要だ".
- If placed like this, the 多い has to work like an adverb : "先生を多く必要とする"
- If one insist on "多い" form, it has to modify the noun "先生": "*多い先生を必要とする" -- and there's one more trap: in such usage, "多くの先生を必要とする" is the proper form. (when you need a young teacher, you can just say "若い先生を必要とする").
- (Additionally, "多い" is many, more is "より多い".)

The proper ways are:

> 先生をより多く必要とすると思います
>
> より多くの先生を必要とすると思います.

Or

> 先生がより多く必要だと思います
>
> より多くの先生が必要だと思います.

In everyday usage, "もっと" might sound more smooth, examples for which are mentioned in @oldergod 's answer.